# How migrate or transfer SQL Server 2008 Compact Edition Database To Express Edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

I have created database in SQL Server 2008 Compact Edition and now I want to migrate that database in SQL Server 2008 Express Edition.

How can I achieve this? Please suggest me the necessary steps. As now, this is my project requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Going from Compact to Express Edition should be as simple as scripting the structures and database objects and recreating them on the SQL Express Edition Instance.  It should be straight forward since Express supports more code than Compact.  Most people encounter problems going from Express to Compact, not vice versa because Compact Edition has a restricted coding model.

In SSMS 2008, you also have the option to Script Data under the Table/View Options of the Scripting Wizard, so you can easily migrate the data using the built in Scripting Wizard in SSMS 2008 as well.  To open the Scripting Wizard, right click on the database Tasks -> Generate Scripts.